# Let $f(x) = x^{2}$. Find two sets A and B for which $f(A \cap B) \neq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm not looking for the answer, I just really need a hint in the right direction. I feel like this should be obvious and it probably is, but my mind is drawing a blank.

Also, if anyone has any input on how to find examples like this, I would be grateful if you can share any tips on how to find counterexamples and examples of functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (-infinity,0) and (0,infinity).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: because $f(x)=x^2=(-x)^2=f(-x)$, it's possible for $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ to have a lot of elements in common even if $A$ and $B$ don't.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the kind of hint I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.  Figure out an example where A and B are disjoint, but their images are not.

Answer (score 0):

To be explicit,
though it looks like
you have figured it out,
$A=[1, 2], B=[-2, -1]$.